# How to combine 2 Date vectors in data frame without changing format

Tags: r

I'm trying to put 2 vectors of dates together in one data frame but when I do they change formats.  Any suggestions?

```
> head(starters)
    [1] "2009-01-02" "2009-02-02" "2009-03-02" "2009-04-01"
    [5] "2009-05-01" "2009-06-01"
    > head(enders)
    [1] "2009-01-30" "2009-02-27" "2009-03-31" "2009-04-30"
    [5] "2009-05-29" "2009-06-30"
    > class(enders)
    [1] "Date"
    > class(starters)
    [1] "Date"
    > comboer <- data.frame(cbind(starters, enders))
    > head(comboer)
      starters enders
    1    14246  14274
    2    14277  14302
    3    14305  14334
    4    14335  14364
    5    14365  14393
    6    14396  14425
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A relevant section of `?cbind` is:

> Any classes the inputs might have are discarded (in particular,
>   factors are replaced by their internal codes).

It's doing something similar to dates as what they describe with factors. You probably just want to do something like this:

```
data.frame(starters = starters, enders = enders)
```